# Trying to sync multiple ip cameras in ffmpeg, having trouble finding the timestamps of each frames being sent

Tags: streaming, time, rtp

I am quite new to ffmpeg. I am wondering if it is possible to get the timestamps of a live video stream from ffmpeg. I read that as the first packet in RTP protocol is sent, it contains the NTP timestamp and the local timestamp of the system. Is there anyway to get this information from ffmpeg, I am using wireshark but I'd like to know if it is possible without wireshark.

Thanks.